# Flex: Do I need to remove event handlers on an AsyncResponder?  If so, how?

Tags: apache-flex

Do I need to remove event listeners on AsyncResponder events?

i.e.

```
    public function DeleteItem():void
    {
        var asyncResponse:AsyncResponder = new AsyncResponder(DeleteItem_Result, DeleteItem_Fail);
        _myService.DeleteWorkout("test", asyncResponse);
    }

    private function DeleteItem_Result(event:Event):void
    {
        //If I do need to remove them, how do i remove the async responder event listeners?
    }
```

If I do need to remove them, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
Do I need to remove event listeners on AsyncResponder events?
```

No, you do not.  If you are creating the AsyncResponder and using ot over and over again, then by all means leave the listeners in there.

However, in some cases, if you won't be reusing the component over and over; I would recommend you do remove the event listeners, as that will remove a dependency pointing at the asyncResponder which may allow it to be released for garbage collection as appropriate.

In the Adobe Flex Framework it is pretty common to add and remove listeners "as needed."  We use the approach in the Flextras Calendar, for example, when dealing with effects.  Before starting the effect we add some event listeners for 'effect end'.  Those listeners are removed in that effect end method.

---

Update:

To remove an event listener you would use code similar to this:

```
asyncResponder.removeEventListener('result' ,UpdatePics_result);
asyncResponder.removeEventListener('fault' ,UpdatePics_fault);
```

Comment: So how do you remove the event?  Normally you would specify the event type and event method, but I only have the event method in this case.

Comment: @Nate you need both the event type and event method to remove the event.  I do not know of a way to automagically figure out the event based on the method.

Comment: How would you do it with the code in my question?  That's the crux of my question, I don't know how to remove an event on an asyncresponder

Comment: @Nate you can't remove an event.  You can only remove the event listener.  I updated my answer.

Comment: How do you remove the event listener when it's not a global variable?

Comment: @Nate If you have no access to the object that fires the event you cannot remove an event listener from it.  Does that answer the question?

Comment: For event listeners on other functions you would do a event.current.RemoveEventListener(...) on the event handler to remove the reference.  This doesn't work with asyncResponders. 

In order for me to use your code above, I have to have a reference to the asyncResponder in the "UpdatePics_Result" function.  As I said above, this is commonly done with regular event listeners.  I just don't know how to reference the AsyncResponder in the event handler function.  I don't want to create global AsyncResponders.

Comment: @Nate You will always need a reference to the object you want to remove event listeners from.  Getting that reference via a property on the event does not change that fact.  I don't know which events you are accessing that have a current property.  Are you referring to the currentTarget property?  or target?  Why can't you use those to remove the event listener?

Comment: I don't understand why we're still talking about a closed question.  If you feel my answer does not address your issue; you should deselect it and update the original question w/ more details.  If you are trying to get an answer to a completely different question related to event listeners; you should post a new question.